# how to force the image to be placed inline

Tags: floats, positioning

despit i specified that the image must be place inline "among the text" using [h] command, at run time, the image is place at the end of the section
how to set it right?

**latex**:

```
\subsection{item1 Vs item2}
in this comparison......
......
......
......
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm,scale=0.7]{osm_vs_wikipedia_2}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

the rest of the text goes here..
...
```

Comment: Did you look at the links I posted in comments to your other question?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes i did, that#s why i used [h]..but [H] generates an error

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in all the links I posted, you need `\usepackage{float}` to use `H`.

Comment: If you have the time, read [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017), and you'll see that `h` does not mean *here, definitely*. `H` on the other hand, disables floating.

Comment: Did it work with `\usepackage{float}`?

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioned in the above-mentioned link: a plain TeX macro package, `insbox.tex`, which defines an `\InsertBoxC` command. This command is to be used inside a paragraph, lets the current line terminate, then inserts its argument, andafterwards continues the text of the paragraph.

Demo:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cleveref, todonotes}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius dapibus metus eget ultrices. Nulla sagittis mauris rutrum, blandit augue eget, laoreet augue. Phasellus enim odio, sagittis in mi sed, fringilla mollis odio. Phasellus quis purus ultricies, tempor purus at, tempus quam. Donec ultricies, ligula ac pretium porttitor, nibh nunc \todo[color=white, linecolor=red]{\color{red}Insertion point}%
%%%
\InsertBoxC{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering\bigskip\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{AliceSteadman.png}\\ \captionof{figure}{Any description}\label{WhiteRabbit}\end{minipage}}%
%%%
Integer eros nibh, cursus at est sed, volutpat tristique justo. Donec ornare facilisis lorem, id feugiat elit pellentesque at. Nulla odio mauris, luctus sed faucibus id, dignissim dictum velit. Morbi vehicula velit at massa tristique rhoncus. Cf. \color{red}{\cref{WhiteRabbit}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not add it to [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625) or [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275) instead?